# How will a Response packet reach from Destination to source after packet has been reached to the destination?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, arp

This would be a very basic question, but I am not able to figure it out.

I am very curious about one thing if anyone could help me that would be really great.
Let’s say we have a router in our home and multiple devices are connected to it like my laptop and my phone.

- My Public IP: 200.12.65.221(Public IP)
- Routers IP: 192.168.0.1 Laptop
- IP assigned by DHCP: 192.168.0.101
- Mobile’s IP: 192.168.0.102

I am sending a request packet with some data to a server from my mobile. let’s say the destination address be 10.0.0.2/24.
So with the above explanation, I understood that my request will be sent to the destination using ARP and hopping through multiple routers.
So my question is what would be the Source IP address for the packet and if it is one of the following this would be my subsequent questions:

- Case: 1- 192.168.0.102
  If the above is the source IP address, then how will the server send the response as it is a local address assigned to the mobile by the DHCP server, which would be ambiguous.
- Case: 2 – 200.12.65.221
  If the above is the IP address then how would we route the response to the mobile device as the packet would reach the router and thereafter how will we know which Local IP address or MAC Address we need to go to.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you sent a packet to the outside world, the router replace the source IP/Port with it's own, it keep this information in memory (untill full transaction happens). once the server recieve the packet it send the response to your router, your router will use the in momory table to find the device that sent the packet and forward the packet to it.

> Network address translation (NAT) is a method of remapping an IP address space into another by modifying network address information in the IP header of packets while they are in transit across a traffic routing device. The technique was originally used to avoid the need to assign a new address to every host when a network was moved, or when the upstream Internet service provider was replaced, but could not route the networks address space. It has become a popular and essential tool in conserving global address space in the face of IPv4 address exhaustion. One Internet-routable IP address of a NAT gateway can be used for an entire private network.

[Read full article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)

Comment: Thanks a ton man, was giving me a hard time thinking 